# How to add the indivdual option menu for posts like facebook ,google Plus

Tags: css, ajax, jquery, drop-down-menu

[image]
[image]

I have made something here at Jsfiddle :)
http://jsfiddle.net/madhu131313/gZWjb/ 
But the problem is I have list of Items when I click on the the dropdown button
all the dropdowns are opening 
Suppose if I put the display none for others ( I dont think this is the correct method because it will make the execution complex) 
How does googleplus ,facebook code look like ?

Comment: could you explain your problem with an example in fiddle? der is only one dropdown in the fiddle now.

Comment: You need to use ID for your link, so you can

`<a href="#menu1" class="menu_drop" id="menu" rel="1">`

Also use

`(this)`, so you can on menu click, (any of the page menu) then slideDown the subMenu for that item set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made the code 
http://jsfiddle.net/madhu131313/xZNAY/

Comment: You could have left me some credit since your using majority of my code. And please post your code setup in here to as jsFiddle goes down too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ID` (`#`) for your link, so you can

```
<a href="#menu1" class="menu_drop" id="menu" rel="1">
```

Also use

`$(this)`, so you can on menu click (any of the page links) then `slideDown` for that subMenu child set.

I have a jsFiddle of something similar and you can see multiple threads that only slide and toggle that particular thread.

http://jsfiddle.net/gZWjb/7/

Comment: +1 for sample.. `REL` is not needed as you can even use `onClick="dropDownMenu()"` and that can detect the ID of that link or `onClick="dropDownShow(2)"` for example.